# Is there any way to call .dll files in PHP over Linux Platform?

Tags: php, dll, com

**Question :** is there any way to call .dll files using php COM class over linux platform?

**Description:** I need to interact with dll files to access inside the functions.
I am successfully register the dll files in windows environment by following below steps.

1. Xampp installation v3.2.1 php 5.5 (Note: currently using version Xampp installation v3.1.2 php 5.3 need to change new/latest version Xampp installation v3.2.1 php 5.5).
2. Download php_com_dotnet.dll file from here,http://originaldll.com/file/php_com_dotnet.dll/29343.html and  copy downloaded file to folder C:\xampp\php\ext.
3. DLL need to be configured under xampp parent folder in C:\xampp\php\ php.ini file
4. Add php_com_dotnet.dll file to windows extension in C:\xampp\php\ php.ini file
5. Restart the xampp server.

**Register DLL file through command prompt:**

•   Click on start button and in search option type cmd and press enter

•   Right click on command prompt and press runasadministrator command

•   Type: regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\dllfilename.dll press enter

•   It shows dll file register successfully message

Comment: No, there is not. Linux is not Windows. Its executable and and its dynamic libraries are very different and have a different format (ELF) and ABI

Comment: Is there any other way to access dll file's function with out register in windows?

Comment: No there is not. Linux cannot use `.dll` files (except thru emulators like Wine which are running *some* Windows executables). Linux has `.so` shared libraries. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), and use Linux on your development machine.

Comment: If this is just to access .Net functions, have you considered using Mono on your Linux server?

Comment: no i never considered Mono what is Mono?

Answer (score 1):

As Linux Platform is different from the windows you have provided equivalent **.so** file for your purpose check your **php.ini** properly you got information regarding there.

Comment: thank u.   how to create .so files do u have any idea?

Comment: It's ok. As you have downloaded .dll file you will get .so file by google it.

Comment: I think you will never gone a make it. Try equivalent option provided in Linux platform to do the things you wanted to do.